# Get $_SERVER['x_forwarded_for'] value from server behind load balancer

Tags: php, load-balancing

Basicly I want to get the user IP. But since my server was behind load balancer, so I get the user IP from `$_SERVER['x_forwarded_for']` value. But the value always missing when the client connect to server using HTTPS. This is what I get if the client connect using HTTP:

```
Array
(
    [HTTP_HOST] => xxx
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => xxx
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46$
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-gb
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-alive
    [HTTP_VIA] => 1.1 ID-0002262071501332 uproxy-6
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 112.215.63.20
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at xxx Port 80</address>

    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
    [SERVER_NAME] => xxx
    [SERVER_ADDR] => xxx
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 174.133.117.12
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => xxx
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] =>
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => xxx
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => xxx
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 33268
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] =>
    [REQUEST_URI] => /test.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /test.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /test.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1454562249.848
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1454562249
)
```

but when using HTTPS, I got this:

```
Array
(
    [HTTPS] => on
    [SSL_TLS_SNI] => xxx
    [HTTP_HOST] => xxx
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-gb
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => mozilla/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 7_0_2 like mac os x) applewebki$
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at xxx Port 44$

    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
    [SERVER_NAME] => xxx
    [SERVER_ADDR] => xxx
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 174.133.117.12
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => xxx
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] =>
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => xxx
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => xxx
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 57456
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] =>
    [REQUEST_URI] => xxx
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => xxx
    [PHP_SELF] => xxx
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1454562275.52
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1454562275
)
```

Really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You need to do the SSL decryption on the load balancer. Otherwise, it can't make any changes to the HTTP data, it just passes it through literally.

Comment: You will need to ask the network team to make changes at Load Balancer end to forward the `x_forwarded_for` header value to the backend webserver in either same header or custom header. We have done it for our application with is behind Load Balancer